# Wicket tester Page with absolute external url

Tags: java, servlets, wicket

I have a servlet that does some business login and then redirects to a wicket page via absolute url as the page is defined with QueryStringUrlCodingStrategy.

Now I need to test that calling the servlet url it redirects to the wicket page that is rendered correctly.

So I need to do something like:

```
MockHttpServletRequest servletRequest = tester.getServletRequest();
String url = "http://localhost" + servletRequest.getServletPath() + "" + servletRequest.getContextPath()    + "/myservlet?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3";
tester.getServletRequest().setURL(url);
tester.processRequestCycle();
tester.assertRenderedPage(ExpectedPage.class);
```

But the absolute url is not recognized from tester.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to split the test? One test testing if the correct url is created and one test testing if the page renders correctly with given parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the servlet is not available in the Tests as it's defined in web.xml and only deployed with a servlet container.

I solved instanciating the Servlet and calling the onGet method manually getting the redirect url to use then to render my Wicket page.